# Swift - Closure in Dictionary Crash

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift, crash, closures

So I had objc code which uses Singleton instance to make pings(using SimplePing) and holds ping request completion blocks. In ObjC it looks like this:

```
@interface SimplePingClient()
{
    NSMutableArray* _currentPings;
    NSMutableDictionary* _currentCallbacks;
}

@end

@implementation SimplePingClient

-(id)init
{
    if( self = [super init] )
    {
        _currentPings = [NSMutableArray new];
        _currentCallbacks = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    }

    return self;
}
```

method to start ping:

```
-(void)pingHostname:(NSString*)hostName andResultCallBlock:(void(^)(NSString* latency))result
{
    TSimplePing* pingClient = [TSimplePing simplePingWithHostName:hostName];
    [_currentPings addObject:pingClient];
    [_currentCallbacks setObject:result forKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:pingClient]];
    pingClient.delegate = self;
    //some other irrelevant code
    ...
}
```

And when SimplePing delegate method is called:

```
- (void)simplePing:(TSimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet
{
    void(^callback)(NSString* latency) = [_currentCallbacks objectForKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:pinger]];
    if( callback )
    {
        //some irrelevant code
        ...
        callback(@"123");//hard coded for test, irrelevant code get this value correctly ;)
        [_currentCallbacks removeObjectForKey:[NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:pinger]];
    }
    [_currentPings removeObject:pinger];
}
```

So this code work flawlessly on objc. However when I try to port this in Swift I keep get error EXC_BAD_ACCESS. To simplify example I just erased everything and it turns out that storing Closure in Dictionary and immediately call it is not working for me:

```
typealias callbackClosure = (String) -> ()

class SimplePingClient: NSObject
{
    // MARK: variables
    var _currentPings = [TSimplePing]()
    var _currentCallbacks: Dictionary<String, callbackClosure> = [String: callbackClosure]()

    private func ping(hostname: String, resultCallback:callbackClosure)
    {
        var pingClient = TSimplePing(hostName: hostname)
        pingClient.delegate = self
        _currentPings.append(pingClient)
        _currentCallbacks[pingClient.hostName] = resultCallback

        if let callback = _currentCallbacks[pingClient.hostName]
        {
            callback("123213")//here program CRASHES
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in code I even try using hostname(which is String) instead of NSValue assuming some memory problems, but it's not the case - still crashing. This error however is surely something with memory management, however I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong. If anyone could point me what I'm missing I'll really apreciate it.

Comment: You should put your answer in an answer and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Owen Hartnett suggested I'm moving solution from answer itself here:

Okay, after another hour of debugging it turns out reason is pretty silly. As I said I'm porting my code, so previously I was using this class as bridged objective-c code, therefore this function:

```
-(void)pingHostname:(NSString*)hostName andResultCallBlock:(void(^)(NSString* latency))result
```

was bridged following way:

```
SimplePingClient.pingHostname(latencyUrl, refreshTime: refreshRate) { (latency: String!) -> () in

   if nil != latency
   {
       //dummy code
   }

}
```

therefore after SimplePingClient became swift class, my new closure signature is(note that now latency is not force unwrapped and is not optional, and also no need to check against nil)

```
SimplePingClient.pingHostname(latencyUrl, refreshTime: refreshRate) { (latency: String) -> () in

       //dummy code

    }
```

So by simply changing method call everything started working. Strange thing that compiler doesn't notice this problem though.